# Syntax for javascript on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm using pym.js to dynamically resize an iframe which is working as expected but ONLY once the browser window is resized. Until then the iframe has a height of around 150px. I'm trying to get this to work on page load so far I've tried:

```
jQuery(document).ready(
  function() {
    var pymParent = new pym.Parent('personalise', '<?php echo $iframeUrl ?>', {});
});
```

Can anyone help me out with the correct syntax?

Comment: Well that is document ready and not window onload.

Answer (score 3):

You could just execute your function when your iframe is loaded with the following code:

```
$(iframe).load(function() {

// Do stuff

});
```

Comment: Sorry if this is basic, I've added the following. Do I need to replace "iframe" or "function" with something?    ' <script>
          $(iframe).load(function() {
    var pymParent = new pym.Parent('personalise', '<?php        echo $iframeUrl ?>', {});
});
    </script> '

Comment: If the iframe that you'd like to resize has a id or class you should change 'iframe' to this. ('.class' or '#id' just like CSS, don't forget to include the apostophes).

Comment: There's no id or class on the iframe since pym.js creates the actual iframe element from the parent id (which in my case is #personalise)

Comment: Ah, I'm not familiar with Pym.js
And at the moment I don't have time to read in to it. Hope someone else can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have `<iframe>` loading issues with Firefox in particular. As you have already mentioned, having `<iframe>` loading on window load.

`window`.<del>load</del>`= init;`

`window.onload = init;`

(correction: **on**load not load)

Here's a crossbrowser example:

```
if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener('load', ready, false)
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent('onload', ready)
```

See [**ARTICLE**](http://javascript.info/tutorial/onload-ondomcontentloaded)

**UPDATE**

Try wrapping your anonymous function up as a declarative function (e.g. pymParent()), then load it on window event.

```
window.onload = pymParent;

function pymParent() {
  var pym = new pym.Parent({'personalise', '<?php echo $iframeUrl ?>', {}});
  return pym;
}
```

Comment: That's helpful thanks. I tried the basic example but I'm probably putting it in the wrong place as I get Cannot set property 'onload' of undefined :               <script>

  document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].onload = function() {

   var pymParent = new pym.Parent('personalise', '<?php echo $iframeUrl ?>', {});
  }
</script>

Comment: I had to adjust the syntax a bit but still no change       window.onload = pymParent;
  function pymParent() {
   var pymParent = new pym.Parent('personalise', '<?php echo $iframeUrl ?>', {});
   return pym;
  }